# Permission denied on getimagesize

Tags: php, permission-denied, getimagesize

In my `functions.php` I got:

```
$size = getimagesize($avatarpath . "/" . $file);
```

`$avatarpath` is `$avatarpath = dirname(__FILE__)."/img/avatars";`

My structure:

functions.php (in the same directory as img folder).
img/avatars

Chmods of functions.php , img, avatars has been set to 777.

And I still receive the following message:

`Warning: getimagesize(/home/godaddy/private_html/img/avatars/avatar_1.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/godaddy/private_html/img/avatars/functions.php on line 1337`

Comment: How about the image itself? Is it 0777?

Comment: Don't forget the directories above as well. You can grant all the permissions you want on the .png file, but if the directory doesn't allow Apache to read inside it, you'll still get permission denied.

Comment: Image itself has this: `@chmod($avatarpath . "/" . $filename, '0644');`

Comment: @MarcB You're saying that I need to grant all permissions on the directories: /home/godaddy/private_html/ too? O_o

Comment: Yes. Otherwise it's like putting a "free take one" pamphlet display inside a vault inside Fort Knox. The pamphlet's free, but you can't get inside to take one.

Comment: Well, those directiories has already a chmod `755` I think thats enough.

Comment: try to check, your php support for gd library. if not, try to install it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the user that php runs under.  If you're with godaddy, they use virtual servers so your php user may not actually have access even if you've chmod'd it.  Find out the user, then chown it to that user and see if it helps.