# Chmod 666 and access denied for getimagesize

Tags: php, chmod, permission-denied

First of all, this is not a duplicate of : [Permission denied on getimagesize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7799478/permission-denied-on-getimagesize)

I got following code, where I sat an `chmod` for the image, and then I wan't to get it's size.

```
@chmod($path."/".$filename, '0666');
getimagesize($path . "/" . $filename);
```

But if I set a chmod, I'm receiving this error message:

> failed to open stream: Permission denied in[...]

What is the problem? All files and the directory has the same group and owner - `www-data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually do you really need to chmod before getimagesize?

if so, maybe u can try putting umask before chmod.
something like this?

```
$old = umask(0); 
chmod($path,0777);
umask($old);
```

Comment: Just curious; what made this work as opposed to other solutions? And what exactly does `umask` do in this case?

Comment: basically it's only giving the PHP request a temporary access and then set it back after u do the chmod.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting a / before path.  Not sure about php, but I know python wont add the initial / to certain path operations, so it may be looking for a relative path instad of absolute:

```
@chmod("/". $path."/".$filename, '0666');
getimagesize("/". $path . "/" . $filename);
```

Comment: It already has an absolute path. `$path = dirname(__FILE__);`

Comment: Ah, then thats all I got, sorry @Cyclone :/.

Comment: No problem. Voted up for tryin ;)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `chmod` won't succeed (permission will be denied; maybe the error you get is from chmod?) if `www-data` (assuming that's the user of your webserver) doesn't have write access to the directory `$path`. Ensure `www-data` has **read-permission to all parent dirs of `$path`** and **write-permission to `$path`**.

Also, ensure that you use absolute paths, both in `chmod` and `getimagesize`.

Comment: What do you mean by saying absolute path? And yes, www-data has read permission to all parent directories. I'm generating my path following way: http://pastebin.com/hj0SUQmF

Comment: An absolute path starts with a `/` and specifies the entire path (all dirs) from the filesystem root down to the file in question. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_path#Unix_style

Comment: It already has an absolute path. `$path = dirname(__FILE__);` dirname is returning an absolute path.

Comment: @Cyclone Yes, I understood that from your pastebin. Sorry for not mentioning that. Try replacing your first line with `print chmod(...);`, and see if it prints `True`, `1` or something -- just to ensure your `chmod` really works.

Comment: It works, since when I remove the line with @chmod~ , there not any errors and everything works, but then , my image has strange chmod `1664`.

Comment: So `getimagesize` works without `chmod`? Please clarify what works and what doesn't, I got confused of your last comment.

Comment: When my chmod is changed to 666 like here: http://pastebin.com/hj0SUQmF . Then I got an error message with permission denied.